# What are the features of hard drive partition?

Tags: windows, windows-8

is it possible to partition an internal hard drive into such a way that the two partition work independently and even the deadliest of virus affecting a partition cannot affect the other partition.

Comment: Given enough effort a virus  can be written to infect every drive or partition it can find automatically.  Best prevent the system from being infected in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

No, at least not without specialized hardware.

Comment: +1 for this answer.  That said, having multiple partitions for things like other OS's can provide some level of protection against some malware - of-course if your partition table is scrambled or the Virus is indiscriminate you are probably SOL anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The best bet you can have is, partitioning your drive smartly & Using User Account Control with a secondary free OS like Linux/Ubuntu installed on other partition.

You can save your pc from deadliest virus attack by providing barriers for it go unnoticeable & spread across the whole machine, for this Make 2 accounts Administrator & Standard, from user account control settings give limited read/write permission to standard user on C: drive(system drive) & no write permission to standard user on other partitioned drive, vice-versa user account control on other drive  on linux/ubuntu.

Now always operate your machine as a standard user, assuming someday a virus attacks & your antivirus system fails, in this scenario the virus will now try to delete or write/corrupt/access files on your C: drive(system drive) or other partition, Windows in reaction to it will prompt for admin password, in this way you can detect a suspicious activity going on on your PC.

Secondly if everything fails and windows get corrupt, still you have a fair chance to recover everything safely, as your machine will have dual boot option using Linux/Ubuntu, u will be able to boot from other drive & manually scan or fix everything back to normal or to the minimum recover your valuable data.